# Request is loading twice in Microsft Edge Browser, when tried to open the URL in window.open

Tags: microsoft-edge

Hi I'm facing an issue that, onclick on hyper link calling script funciton which opens the URL in window.open.

In netwrok tab Noticed that URL request is sending twice, for one reposne code is 302(doesn have nay response data) and for another one response code is 200(which has reponse data), This behaviour in Microsoft edge browser.

In internet explore noticed behaviour is different, on click on hyperlink seeing request is sending twice, both requests are getting succesfull with response code 200 with proper response data.

Below is the code I've done so far of the Hyper link. Can some one help me why multiple request are triggering how to fix this to trigger only one request.

`<a tabindex="13" title="This link will open a new browser window that contains the user details."`

```
onclick="javascript:openChildWindow('http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/xxxx/channel/session.cgi?sessargs=p47iorSBMUG1tKkTcNpjM4qNdGTees3H');return false;" 

href="http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/xxxx/channel/channel/session.cgi?sessargs=NliOOYGLmDf1yePDXopw8o2IMx2HYyg1">View details</a>
```

Comment: I made a test with MS Edge and able to produce the issue. In my testing I made a test with Edge 42 and Edge 44. In both versions of Edge, Issue is producible with any request. I will try to provide feedback to Edge developers regarding this issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Any updates? I have the same problem in Edge 42.x, Windows 10 Version 1803. Has this been fixed in Version 1903 (May, 2019)? Can you confirm if the issue is also present in Version 1809? Very odd. It's also reproducible with href, in my experience. No JS needed. Sends double request. One with session data and one without. If I place http proxy debugger like fiddler in between, then only one request is sent, as it should, not two. Very odd bug and I'm really surprised it's not been reported as an emergency patch.

Comment: similar behaviour with fireing a wordpress plugin "publish" hook